# Write a recursive function called print_num_pattern() to output the following number pattern

Tags: python

Write a recursive function called print_num_pattern() to output the following number pattern.

Given a positive integer as input (Ex: 12), subtract another positive integer (Ex: 3) continually until 0 or a negative value is reached, and then continually add the second integer until the first integer is again reached.

For coding simplicity, output a space after every integer, including the last. Do not end output with a newline.

Ex. If the input is:

12
3
the output is:

12 9 6 3 0 3 6 9 12

My code:

```
def print_num_pattern(num1,num2):

    if (num1 == 0 or num1 < 0):
       print(num1, end = ' ')
       return

   print(num1, end = ' ')
   if num1 - num2 <= 0:
       return
   print_num_pattern(num1 - num2, num2)
   print(num1, end = ' ')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   num1 = int(input())
   num2 = int(input())
   print_num_pattern(num1, num2)
```

My output
12 9 6 3 6 9 12
Expected output
12 9 6 3 0 3 6 9 12

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_num_pattern(num1,num2): 

    if (num1 == 0 or num1 < 0): 
        print(num1, end = ' ') 
        return

    print(num1, end = ' ') 
    print_num_pattern(num1 - num2, num2) 

    print(num1, end = ' ')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   num1 = int(input())
   num2 = int(input())
   print_num_pattern(num1, num2)
```